# trouble with syntax about includes

Tags: php

I am sure this is a very simple thing to handle, however, as I am a newbie I seem to have ran out of options.

I am currently using the following code in my header and footer file.  I realize this is a bad practice to do this and would like to find out how to write the correct syntax so all the files in any directory can point to only one path.  I hope I explained this right.

```
<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>        
<?php include("../includes/footer.php"); ?>  
<?php include ("../../includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

If I delete one or two of the paths above I run into problems.  I don't think I am doing this right.  Unless I am not sure of myself and this is the way to handle such thing in php.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there only one footer? or many? What is the error message you are getting? If there is only one file and if you are getting the error, then that means your path is not right.

Comment: Use the absolute paths started with `__DIR__`

Comment: I am not sure I understand you zerkms.  my apologies.  can you show an example

Comment: only one footer and one header file

Comment: `__DIR__` is a "magic constant" that gives you the directory of the current file: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple invocation points, then relative paths won't work reliably throughout includes. Use an absolute path then, define a `BASE_DIR` constant.

Or if your include folder is beneath the webservers root directory:

```
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/includes/footer.php");
```

Comment: missing ' in your global... `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` vs `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` unless you have DOCUMENT_ROOT defined as a constant..

Comment: The syntax in double quote context differs there. Adding quotes would be a syntax error unless you also introduce curly braces around the varexpression.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for that information. Usually, I just concat the DOCUMENT_ROOT in a require_once and append the name of the file in question

Comment: does this also apply to .css file

Comment: no. css files are client side, you can use the / to load css files from the document root. i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">` will load the style.css file from the document root.

Comment: @user3001162 Alternatively use a `<base href=..>` to normalize resource references (images and css).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your directory structure.

If you have for example:

```
/index.php
/pages/testPage.php
/includes/footer.php
```

Then in index.php you will need to use `<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>`
but in testPage.php you will need to use `<?php include("../includes/footer.php"); ?>`

The ".." means up one folder. If your directory structure is similar to my example you should be able to use `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php"); ?>` on every page

Comment: I tried to have only /includes/footer.php  putting the / in front of the first path and deleting the other two, but it did not work for other pages.  Index.php was good.

Comment: / will try loading from the server's root directory. You will need the complete path of the file... `<?php echo getcwd(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks again and my apologies for the inconvenience.  I know this is an easy thing to figure out on my own but after coding all day, i can hardly think straight.  Cheers!